# How to check if one pattern is included into another

Tags: java, regex

For example, I have the following regular expression:

> /lol.*

All strings that matches this expression also matches another expression:

> /l.*

How to check that first regex is included into the second one (using JAVA libraries)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a lookahead in the second regex inorder to check if the first regex is present in the second or not.

```
\/l(?=ol).*
```

In java you don't need to escape forward slash. So the below regex would be enough.

```
l(?=ol).*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/mR2rE1/1)

Comment: I don't want to check strings, I want to check inclusion. Imagine that I have only two regexes without any information about them.